# Does robocopy copies 'hidden' and/or 'system' files and folders by default?

Tags: windows

When running robocopy using a most basic command such as

```
robocopy <Source> <Destination> /E
```

does it only copies what I would call 'regular' files and folders, or those with hidden and system attributes as well ?

The official doc at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy does not even mention hidden or system attributes (as of 2020-02-01).

For the record I'm on Windows 10 1909 (18363.592).

Answer (score 6):

I did some tests.

First I disabled "Hide protected operating system files" in Folder options. Then I created some folders and files and changed their attributes in `cmd` using

```
attrib +s +h <folder or file path>
```

Then copying using the command

```
robocopy <Source> <Destination> /E
```

did in fact copy all files and folders, regardless of their `system` or `hidden` attributes.

Additionally, I tested copying the contents of the "real" system folder `$Recycle.Bin` to another folder. It did copy the contents although Windows Explorer does not display the original complex folder names in the destination folder.
[image: copy of the $Recycle.Bin content]